# Draw to Canvas periodically in Dart

Tags: canvas, dart, flutter

Hi I am quite new to Dart. What I would like to achieve is to draw on canvas periodically leaving the previous stuff there.

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;


Duration timeBase;
double x = 0.0;
double y = 0.0;
int i = 0;

ui.Image image;

void beginFrame(Duration timeStamp){
  Timeline.timeSync('beginFrame',(){
    if(timeBase == null)timeBase = timeStamp;
    final double devicePixelRatio = ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
    // paint
    ui.Rect paintBounds = ui.Offset.zero & ui.window.physicalSize;
    ui.PictureRecorder recorder = new ui.PictureRecorder();
    ui.Canvas canvas = new ui.Canvas(recorder,paintBounds);
    if(image != null){
      canvas.drawImage(image,ui.Offset.zero,new ui.Paint());
    }

    var paint = new ui.Paint();
    paint.color = const ui.Color.fromARGB(255,0,255,0);
    paint.strokeCap = ui.StrokeCap.round;
    paint.strokeWidth = 17.0;
    canvas.drawLine(new ui.Offset(x,y),new ui.Offset(x + 25,y + 25),paint);
    x = x + 1;
    if(x > ui.window.physicalSize.width / devicePixelRatio){
      x = x - ui.window.physicalSize.width / devicePixelRatio;
    }
    y = y + 1;
    if(y > ui.window.physicalSize.height / devicePixelRatio){
      y = y - ui.window.physicalSize.height / devicePixelRatio;
    }


    ui.Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();
    image = picture.toImage(ui.window.physicalSize.width.toInt(),ui.window.physicalSize.height.toInt());


    // composite
    Float64List deviceTransform = new Float64List(16)
      ..[0] = devicePixelRatio
      ..[5] = devicePixelRatio
      ..[10] = 1.0
      ..[15] = 1.0;
    ui.SceneBuilder sceneBuilder = new ui.SceneBuilder()
      ..pushTransform(deviceTransform)
      ..addPicture(ui.Offset.zero,picture)
      ..pop();
    ui.window.render(sceneBuilder.build());
  });
  ui.window.scheduleFrame();
}
void main() {
  ui.window.onBeginFrame = beginFrame;
  ui.window.scheduleFrame();
}
```

The problem is that previous image, draw with method drawImage did not appear on canvas.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been [fixed](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/3691). If you're on the master branch, run `flutter upgrade` and you should be good to go.

Here's what it looks like:[image: screenshot]